# Can 406558142992290754819586 be expressed as the sum of two fourth powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

Is 406558142992290754819586 the sum of two fourth powers? I suspect that this number is the sum of two fourth powers. Can anyone use Wolfram Mathematica , SAGE , or some computer program, to check whether this number is the sum of two fourth powers ?

The complete factorization of this number is given by : 406558 142992 290754 819586 = 2 × 17 x 17 × 21529 × 10 052297 × 3250 166849 Notice that all the factors are of the form 16n+1 or 16n+9 ( they are all  congruent to  1 mod 8 ). Hence this number may be the sum of two fourth powers.

Comment: Why this particular number?

Comment: Maple says no, after about 4 seconds of computation.

Comment: Dear Winther@  I am looking for counterexamples  to the Euler Quartic Conjecture.  This particular number turns up in my search  for counterexamples.

Comment: The paper [On $A^4 + B^4 + C^4 = D^4$](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0930224-9/S0025-5718-1988-0930224-9.pdf) by N. Elkies might be of interest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; your number is congruent to $11$ modulo $13$, whereas fourth powers are congruent to either $0$, $1$, $3$ or $9$ modulo $13$.

Comment: How did you choose/find 13? Did you just try all small numbers, or did you somehow know/guess that 13 might work?

Comment: I looked at primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, as they will have few quartic residues. For $p=5$ the only quartic residues are $0$ and $1$, but unfortunately the given number is congruent to $1$ modulo $5$. For $p=13$ the three nonzero residues are quickly computed to be $1$, $3$ and $9$, and Wolfram Alpha told me the given number is congruent to $11$ modulo $13$.